# How to pose to look 'cooler' or more 'dashing' in a photo?

Tags: technique, posing, group-photos

I know it's a stupid question, but I find whenever someone unprofessional takes my picture or groupfie, I end up looking a little unprepared and never 'cool', 'dashing' or even smiling.

What tips or tricks could be given so I look better in photos (I'm the one in the blue shirt)?

[image: it is me in blue shirt in that photo]

Comment: Ummm.... which one are you, and which of those people do you want to look more like?

Comment: @PhilipKendall in that pic I,wearing a blue shirt sitting in right side of that pic. You see I am with no attitude,not smiling,not looking cool.

Comment: Ummm… the minority of the guys in the picture is smiling. I'd say only the guy in the shirt with blue and white stripes is smiling.

Comment: The term 'groupfie' exists? I feel like I don't want to live in this world anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this specific picture one thing happened to you.

You are crouched next to two standing people. That has no sense. It was probably because you wanted to be "too" inventive, because you are too worried of doing something cool.

**Interacting group**

Depending on how really close the group are (and I do not mean spacing) the interactions reflect that. Probably it is also a cultural thing. Some cultures are less "expressive" than others.

Let us take a look at some stock images: https://www.google.com/search?q=happy+group+photo The basic idea is that people interacts. In almost none of thoose random images no person try to stand out. The full group include someone else.

If you want to be more expressive (different than cool) simply hug the persons arround and do not be afraid of smiling.

**What you can learn**

When directing people to protrait photos, one technique to smile is to do it but do not close your lips. Breath trhu the mouth. That opens a bit the mouth and gives a more natural look.

Another tip when directing people if for some reason you can not hug all the people arround you while standing, is do something with your arms. Cross them, take them to your belt, etc.

**Do not worry too much**

I do not see wrong that you learn this kind of posing tips. If this is part of learning things that make feel us more comfortable it is great.

But never fake things. Be yourself.

**As this is a photography forum**

If you are the one on the other side of the camera, please include the feet of the persons in the front row!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are too aware of what others may think about you. You need to know that the people surrounding you are just passing by, even if they think anything about you, it is just for that moment. People pass by, but the photographs you take stays life long. So loosen yourself, let the pranks out!

Also, bring a tripod whenever you shoot in low light - it really helps with the light.

Happy shoots!

Comment: thanks bro for your precise advice. Will try to keep it in mind always